# Next Js: How to call external REST API without showing the request on the client side(Network tab)

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js

I am creating an application in Next.js(Frontend) and Php(Backend: REST API). Now what I want is whenever the user submits the form I want to get the form data from react js and post it to the REST API developed in Php. But I don't want to show the request on the Network tab as the request contains some sensitive data like token's etc. Is there a way that I can achieve this ? I am able to get the initial data using `getServerSideProps()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot hide the data in the Network tab. If you are dealing with sensible data you can encrypt the data before it gets send to the server and decrypt the data afterwards in the backend (PHP code).